# numpyからpytorchへの変換

Tags: python, numpy, pytorch

機械学習の予測プログラムを作っているのですが，tensorflowで書いたモデルとpytorchで書いたモデルの2つを作っています．
tensorflowベースで書いた予測モデルをpytorchベースのものに変換したいのですが，うまく行かないです．どのように対処すべきでしょうか？ご教示の程，お願い致します．

**処理の流れ:**

1. 10秒間データを習得し（1×8配列），リストに入れる．
2. その最頻値を出し，その最大値を別のリストに入れる．
3. その値を計算グラフで計算する．

print(data) → `[1,4,5,6,7,3,1,3], [1,2,3,4,5,6,7,8],,,,` です．

#### エラーメッセージ

```
response = np.argmax(np.bincount(temp))# numpy形式
File "<__array_function__ internals>", line 6, in bincount
only one element tensors can be converted to Python scalars
```

#### コード

```
if __name__ == '__main__':

    myo.init(bin_path=r'C:\Users\name\Desktop\myo-sdk-win-0.9.0\bin')
    HUB = myo.Hub()
    model.eval()
    listener = MyListener()
    start = time.time()
    temp = [] # リストを作成
    with HUB.run_in_background(listener.on_event):
        while True:
            data = listener.get_emg_data()  # 取得する筋電信号
            if time.time() - start >= 10:
                response = np.argmax(np.bincount(temp))# numpy形式
                response = torch.tensor(response)　# tensorに変換
                print(response)
                print("Predicted gesture: {0}".format(response))
                temp = []　
                start = time.time()

            if len(data) > 0:              # len(data) = 8
                tmp = []
                for v in listener.get_emg_data():
                    tmp.append(v[1])
                tmp = list(np.stack(tmp).flatten())
                tmp = torch.tensor(tmp)  # tensor型に変換（listの中身を）
                print(tmp)
                if len(tmp) >= 64:
                    pred = model(tmp)
                    #pred = torch.mean(_,predicted, feed_dict={x: np.array([tmp])})
                    #pred = sess.run(y_pred_cls, feed_dict={x: np.array([tmp])})
                    print(pred)
                    temp.append(pred[0])
            sleep(0.01)
```

Comment: ちなみにハードウェアを使ったデータ収集と同時に動作させているようなので、それを持たない他の人は手を出しにくいかもしれません。データ収集と機械学習の部分を分離して蓄積したデータを公開すると助言や回答が得られ易いのでは？ また今回のような変換時にも過去データを使った検証が簡単に出来るのでは？

Comment: 仰る通りでした．大変申しわけありません．

Comment: データは以下のような形です．[(1609922196940975, [-2, 0, 2, -1, 2, 0, 1, 1]), (1609922196940975, [2, 0, 0, -1, 0, 0, -2, 1]),，，，，

Answer (score 0):

状況をしっかり把握できているわけではないのですが、
`response = np.argmax(np.bincount(temp))# numpy形式`
の箇所で`temp`の型が何か合わないのではないかと思いました。

今手元の環境で動かしてみたところ、例えば以下であれば通るようです。
`np.bincount(([1,2,3,4,1,2,3,4]))`
`np.bincount(np.array([1,2,3,4,1,2,3,4]))`
今は`temp`の形状はどのようになっているでしょうか？1月6日のコメントで

> データは以下のような形です．[(1609922196940975, [-2, 0, 2, -1, 2, 0, 1, 1]), (1609922196940975, [2, 0, 0, -1, 0, 0, -2, 1]),，，，，

とありますが、こちらは`temp`のことでしょうか？私の環境下で

```
temp = [(1609922196940975, [-2, 0, 2, -1, 2, 0, 1, 1]), (1609922196940975, [2, 0, 0, -1, 0, 0, -2, 1])]
np.argmax(np.bincount(temp))
```

を実行したところ、発生したエラーは`ValueError: object too deep for desired array`となったので、それとは違うのかなと思ったのですが…。
tempの型を変換してみて、もしくは具体的な値を入力してみて、通りそうな型を探ってみるのはいかがでしょうか。